# Get full screen preview with Android camera2

Tags: android, camera, camera2, android-camera2

I'm building a custom camera using the new camera2 API. My code is based on the code sample provided by Google [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Video).

I can't find a way to get the camera preview in full screen. In the code sample, they use ratio optimization to adapt to all screens but it's only taking around 3/4 of the screen's height.

Here is my code of `AutoFitTextureView` :

```
public class AutoFitTextureView extends TextureView {

private int mRatioWidth = 0;
private int mRatioHeight = 0;

public AutoFitTextureView(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public AutoFitTextureView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public AutoFitTextureView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

/**
 * Sets the aspect ratio for this view. The size of the view will be measured based on the ratio
 * calculated from the parameters. Note that the actual sizes of parameters don't matter, that
 * is, calling setAspectRatio(2, 3) and setAspectRatio(4, 6) make the same result.
 *
 * @param width  Relative horizontal size
 * @param height Relative vertical size
 */
public void setAspectRatio(int width, int height) {
    if (width < 0 || height < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Size cannot be negative.");
    }
    mRatioWidth = width;
    mRatioHeight = height;
    requestLayout();
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

    if (0 == mRatioWidth || 0 == mRatioHeight) {
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    } else {
        if (width < height * mRatioWidth / mRatioHeight) {
            setMeasuredDimension(width, width * mRatioHeight / mRatioWidth);
        } else {
            setMeasuredDimension(height * mRatioWidth / mRatioHeight, height);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

this is the solution for your problem. In this [line](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Video/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2video/Camera2VideoFragment.java#L236) the aspect ratio is set to 3/4. I changed *chooseVideSize* method to pick video size with hd resolution for *MediaRecorder*.

```
    private static Size chooseVideoSize(Size[] choices) {
        for (Size size : choices) {
            // Note that it will pick only HD video size, you should create more robust solution depending on screen size and available video sizes
            if (1920 == size.getWidth() && 1080 == size.getHeight()) {
                return size;
            }
        }
        Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't find any suitable video size");
        return choices[choices.length - 1];
    }
```

Then I corrected [this method](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Video/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/camera2video/Camera2VideoFragment.java#L255) to pick preview size accordingly to video size aspect ratio and below is result.

```
private static Size chooseOptimalSize(Size[] choices, int width, int height, Size aspectRatio) {
    // Collect the supported resolutions that are at least as big as the preview Surface
    List<Size> bigEnough = new ArrayList<Size>();
    int w = aspectRatio.getWidth();
    int h = aspectRatio.getHeight();
    double ratio = (double) h / w;
    for (Size option : choices) {
        double optionRatio = (double) option.getHeight() / option.getWidth();
        if (ratio == optionRatio) {
            bigEnough.add(option);
        }
    }

    // Pick the smallest of those, assuming we found any
    if (bigEnough.size() > 0) {
        return Collections.min(bigEnough, new CompareSizesByArea());
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't find any suitable preview size");
        return choices[1];
    }
}
```

I hope it will help you!

Comment: It worked ! Thank you so so much @MrOnyszko! 

Did you implemented also autofocus when you tap on the screen? My preview image is a little bit blurry now.

Comment: @J.M. using your code I am getting extra white space on the right side of my screen, any way to solve that? If I pick any of the other aspect ratios they are too blurry or cut off at the bottom.

Comment: Could you provide device information such as screen size, preferred preview size, preferred preview size for video?

Comment: It is showing horizontal lines in preview and distorted preview. What could be the possible issue?

Comment: This is working well but the camera quality being less as i feel.

Comment: The `Size` class is only returning within 960x720 and below dimensions. So how you get size as 1920x1080 ? @MrOnyszko

Comment: If the camera preview quality became bad so put max instead of min `Collections.max(bigEnough, new CompareSizesByArea());`

Answer (score 26):

You should change measured width and height to cover full screen, not to fit the screen as below.

From:

```
if (width < height * mRatioWidth / mRatioHeight)
```

to

```
if (width > height * mRatioWidth / mRatioHeight)
```

It worked fine for me.

Comment: I don't think this work. This would distort the image (squeezing on the sides in portrait mode)

Comment: Hi,I followed your answer its great that preview is coming full screen but video that recorded is rotated by 180 dg,can you give solution for that,Thank you

Comment: Excellent solution, it seems - works from my tests so far

Comment: if you use the this solution width gets stretched a bit

Comment: This doesn't work when the activity is in landscape.

Comment: Used this solution and thought it works. I used it for front camera but the image in the camera is not centred.

Comment: You saved my day dear. Thanks :)